# How do I monitor multiple lambda function which are a part of micro service application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, serverless

We are trying to follow a micro-server architecture in our approach.
We have our front end in our S3 bucket and Apis in the API gateway connected to the Lambda function.

so the request flow would be something similar to this:

S3 -> API -> Lambda -> DB

The concern that I have is, how do I know if my API has triggered a lambda function?
there are monitoring options available for lambda but those are post invocation of lambda function.

Is there a way I can know if my lambda function is triggered or not from the API? also send the notification on same?

Comment: AWS X-ray is usually used to follow invocation path. Have you looked at it?

Comment: I have looked at it. I am checking at pre invocation step. X-ray check how lambda performed and the success rate of execution i guess

Comment: Cloudwatch lambda insights..

Comment: @Marcin looking somewhere between the step of API -> Lambda. 
How do I know if my API was able to call the Lambda. OR should I hadle it from the front end?

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya insights, This holds the information of Lambda performance. 
I am trying to check if lambda is being invoked or not.

Comment: If you have CloudTrial's trial setup for lambda invocations, it should have this information.

Comment: @Marcin any documentation I can refer to for this?

Comment: You can check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html).

Comment: @Marcin could you help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the CloudTrial's Trial event for [lambda invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html)  on my own API gateway with lambda. It has the form:

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.07",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AWSService",
        "invokedBy": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "eventTime": "2020-10-30T12:03:17Z",
    "eventSource": "lambda.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "Invoke",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
        "xxxx": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:function:fff",
        "sourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:xxx:84j28c7zga/test/ANY/test"
    },
    "responseElements": null,
    "additionalEventData": {
        "functionVersion": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:function:fff:$LATEST"
    },
    "requestID": "bc5f574e-58d8-4a2b-978b-5ec32aba447e",
    "eventID": "2345b878-4998-4317-a0c4-1005df40d873",
    "readOnly": false,
    "resources": [
        {
            "accountId": "xxxx",
            "type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "ARN": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxx:function:fff"
        }
    ],
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": false,
    "recipientAccountId": "xxxx",
    "sharedEventID": "1906ed81-6835-4046-943d-f2ca9e5b9d40",
    "eventCategory": "Data"
}
```

As you can see above, when the lambda is invoked, you **get information** that it was API gateway which invoked it:

```
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AWSService",
        "invokedBy": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that easier than cloud trail, When your lambda invoked by APIGW, on the lambda event you have some details you can use match your use cases.
Event schema: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html

For example, NodeJS Lambda:

```js
const handler = async (event, context) => {
    if(event["requestContext"] && event["httpMethod"]) {
        console.log("This is probably an API-GW event");
    } else {
        console.log("This is definitely not an API-GW event");
    }
};
```

Another cool way is to use some of the monitoring tools that give you these abilities out of the box:
[Like this tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux7Rd.png)

Full disclosure, The tool I just showed called lumigo, the company I work for.
This is a great tool and I'm using it for my personal projects also